# How do you position a background image inside a <div>?

Tags: background, background-image, css

My code currently looks like this:

```
<div style="position: fixed; width: 35.25%; height: 6.75%;
    left: 0%; top: 4.625%; right: 64.75%; bottom: 88.625%;
    color: #D1E231; text-align: center; background-color: #666666;
    background-image: url('FleurTR.png'); background-position: right top;">
<div>
```

The `<div>` shows up just fine, with the grey background color, but the background image won't show up at all. What am I missing here? There's no reason I should have to specify background-attachment or background-repeat, right? (I don't want it to repeat.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that image referenced correctly? Like, is it not in a folder:

```
background-image: url('/images/myimage.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try testing it with an image linked from the web.

Comment: That's a great idea for testing. Wish I had thought of that.